# Calling method via coroutine gives NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have some simple methods for turning on and off gameObjects in my scene. The following work if called directly

```
 public void turnOn(){
   GameObject foo = GameObject.FindWithTag("foo_tag");
   Debug.Log("1 ASSERT YES foo = "+foo);
  foo.SetActive(true); 
 }

 public void turnOff(){
 GameObject foo = GameObject.FindWithTag("foo_tag");
 Debug.Log("2 ASSERT YES foo = "+foo);
 foo.SetActive(false); 
 }
```

And for testing purposes I want make my gameObjects active again after a certain interval so I've created a coroutine like so. But when using this coroutine the foo reference in both turnOff and turnOn is Null, why?

```
 void Start () {

turnOff();
StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime(2));
}



IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(float time)
 {
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

  // Code to execute after the delay
 turnOn();
 }
```

Comment: You should pass the reference of game object you want to turn on or off. Once game objects is not active find with tag will return null.

Answer (score 2):

FindWithTag only returns active GameObjects last I checked.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, FindWithTag only works for objects active in the scene. Since you set it inactive after finding it the first time: **poof**. If you cache a reference to the object when you first find it, you can use that to re-enable the object afterward.

For example:

```
private GameObject foo_reference;

public void turnOff()
{
    foo_reference = GameObject.FindWithTag( "foo_tag" );
    Debug.Log( "2 ASSERT YES foo = " + foo_reference );
    foo_reference.SetActive( false );
}

public void turnOn()
{
    Debug.Log( "1 ASSERT YES foo = " + foo_reference );
    foo_reference.SetActive( true );
}
```